# Command echo & read

Tags: linux

I want to display "Your year of birth"(e.g) and then read a maximum of 4 characters into the variable YEAR.

I used the command;

```
echo "Your year of birth: "; read -n 4 $year
```

, but displays only year and to read displays

```
read: '1995': not a valid identifier
```

I do not understand why I do not read ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable to without the leading `$` to read, like this:

```
read -n4 year
echo "You was born in $year"
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you provide to `read` is not the *expansion* of the variable, but the actual *name* of the variable, so change to

```
read -n4 year
```

After that command you can use `$year` and it will expand to what you input to `read`.